# Preventing XCode from auto-versioning files

Tags: xcode, git

This is a general XCode question but here goes.

When a nib is opened, XCode auto-versions it, causing it to appear as a changed file in Git/SourceTree. This occurs regardless of whether any real changes have occurred in the nib. The behavior occurs in other file types as well, like image asset catalogs.

When working in a large app with many nibs or large asset catalogs, opening/closing without changes can result in a large list of changed files and increase the chances of unintentionally staging and committing, etc.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent XCode from auto-versioning? Thanks!

Comment: If there are actually no changes, staging and committing will do nothing in git. If you're seeing it "unintentionally staging and committing", that means that something actually *did* change.

Comment: XCode makes actual changes to the file, so sometimes it becomes a big hassle to scroll through the list in SourceTree and determine which are real changes and those that are not

Comment: @IanMacDonald XIBs and storyboards store the build numbers of the version of Xcode and OS X that wrote the file. Even when you don't modify anything in the file, Xcode rewrites the file with new build numbers if the build numbers in the file don't match Xcode's. There is no reason to commit these changes alone to git.

Comment: So why wouldn't you want those changes to persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preferences, uncheck "Add and remove files automatically".

[image: xcode source control preferences screeshot]